# Convert to view model, EF Partial Class calculated property using related entities returns 0

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5 and have a new property that I've defined in a partial class to extend the base database fields. It requires summing data from a related table.

```
[Display(Name = "Qty Allocated")]
        public decimal QtyAllocated
        {
            get { return this.AllocatedContainers == null ? 1 : this.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty); }
            //get { return 2;}
        }
```

This property returns the correct value....BUT, if I then use the following method to convert this to a view model, the returned value is 0. Note the view model inherits from the class:

```
public class InventoryContainerDetailListViewModel : InventoryContainerDetail
```

Method:

```
    public IEnumerable<InventoryContainerDetailListViewModel> ConvertClassToViewModel(IEnumerable<InventoryContainerDetail> entityList)
{
   IEnumerable<InventoryContainerDetailListViewModel> itemGrid =
        from l in entityList.ToList()
        select new InventoryContainerDetailListViewModel()
        {
            Id = l.Id,
            InventoryContainerHeaderId = l.InventoryContainerHeaderId,
            PONbr = l.ReceiptDetail == null ? (int?)null : l.ReceiptDetail.PODetail.POHeaderId,
            ReceiptDetailId = l.ReceiptDetailId,
            ItemId = l.ItemId,
            ItemDescription = l.Item.ShortDescription,
            QtyInContainer = l.QtyInContainer,
            //QtyAllocated = l.AllocatedContainers == null ? 0 : l.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty),
            Location = l.InventoryContainerHeader.Location.DisplayLocation
        };

    return itemGrid;
}
```

In this method, the input parameter entityList does show each item with the correct calculated values, but after the conversion, the value is always 0.

I assume this has something to do with the fact that I am inheriting from the base class, but can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the reason is inheritance. The more probable reason is that `AllocatedContainers` is empty collection (you don't assign it when creating instance of your view model).

Comment: Thanks for your input...I think I understand in concept what you are saying, but am not clear on how to achieve that. How do I assign it when creating an instance of the view model?

Comment: You must either fill it from the real entity loaded by EF or you must simply compute it on that entity and assign it to the view model.

Comment: It is already computed in the entity (which is passed into the method in the entityList parameter) and I can see it there. Since this view model inherits the QtyAllocated property from the entity, I thought it would carry over. I can't assign QtyAllocated a value because it is a read only calculated property on the entity. So what I did was to create a new property in the view model and then assign it's value from the entity, i.e. QuantAlloc = l.QtyAllocated. It just seems like extra unnecessary work and class maintenance I was hoping to avoid by inheriting the property from the entity.